# Magento display only products purchased at least one time

Tags: php, html, css, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to find a way to display only products purchased at least one time *(That means if a product was purchased at least one time(QTY = 1)). I found a good extension on MagentoCommunity Connect named (Magento Bestseller Products Extension) But I can't see any setting to show only posts with at least on sale.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically it can be done like this:

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array('sfoi' => $productCollection->getTable('sales/order_item'))
            ,sprintf('%s.entity_id = sfoi.product_id AND sfoi.parent_item_id IS NULL', Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS)
            ,array())
       ->group(
              sprintf('%s.entity_id',
                       Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::MAIN_TABLE_ALIAS)
       );
    foreach($productCollection as $product){
        echo "Product Name:".$product->getName().",Product ID:".$product->getId()."\n";
    }
```

You can add additional attributes with addAttributeToSelect (just add it the same way like it is written for "name")